# Probability Question On Casting The Winning Vote

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is a question that has to do with voting. The question is that what are the odds that my vote matters? The assumptions are that I would be the last person to cast my vote, there are an even number of voters before me (say this number is the population), and each voter was 50/50 likely to vote for either of the two candidates. What I need to answer is the general formula for the probability that I will cast the deciding vote based on the population.

Here is my work: I think this sounds like a binomial distribution problem. The deciding vote means that there are the same amount of votes for candidate A as candidate B.
Therefore, the formula for the probability is that

$$ P(x = n/2) =  {n \choose n/2} (1/2)^{n/2}*(1/2)^{n/2}. $$

Am I on the right track? It seems like I am missing something but I'm not sure what it is. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: This is correct if we were to assume that each voter was in fact voting uniformly and independently at random (*which is highly unlikely in the real world*).  Note that this is not an equivalent statement to "your vote matters" however.

Comment: So would it be that the probability I will cast the deciding vote is this?   $$P(x = \frac{n}{2}+ 1) + (x = \frac{n}{2}- 1)= {n \choose \frac{n}{2} + 1} (1/2)^{n/2 + 1} (1/2)^{n/2 -1} + {n \choose \frac{n}{2} - 1}(1/2)^{n/2 - 1} (1/2)^{n/2 +1} $$